# Most simple way to get string containing time interval

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-chrono

I'm new to `std::chrono` and I'm looking for a simple way to construct a `string` containing a time interval formatted hhh:mm:ss (yes, 3 hour figures), indicating the difference between a start time point and now.

How would I go about this using a `steady_clock`? The [examples on Cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point) don't quite fit this problem.

Comment: hour hour hour: minute minute : second second

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any function to format a string from a `duration` object. You might have to resort to get the duration in seconds, and then use arithmetic to get the seconds, minutes and hours from that duration, and manually format the string from those numbers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any time you find yourself manually applying conversion factors among units with the `<chrono>` library, you should be asking yourself:

> Why am I converting units manually?  Isn't this what `<chrono>` is
>   supposed to do for me?!

A "conversion factor" is 60, or 1000, or 100, or whatever.  If you see it in your code, you're opening yourself up to conversion factor errors.

Here is sasha.sochka's code rewritten without these conversion factors.  And just to throw in how general this technique is, milliseconds are added for flare:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    steady_clock::time_point start;
    steady_clock::time_point now = steady_clock::now();

    auto d = now -start;
    auto hhh = duration_cast<hours>(d);
    d -= hhh;
    auto mm = duration_cast<minutes>(d);
    d -= mm;
    auto ss = duration_cast<seconds>(d);
    d -= ss;
    auto ms = duration_cast<milliseconds>(d);

    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << hhh.count() << ':' <<
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << mm.count() << ':' << 
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << ss.count() << '.' <<
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << ms.count();
    std::string result = stream.str();
    std::cout << result << '\n';
}
```

There are other ways to do this without exposed conversion factors, this way is only an example.  My main point is: avoid hardcoding unit conversion factors in your code.  They are error prone.  Even if you get it right when you first code it, conversion factors are vulnerable to future code maintenance.  You can future-proof your code by demanding that all unit conversions happen within the `<chrono>` library.

Answer (score 5):

As Joachim Pileborg noted higher in the comments there is no function for format a string from a `duration` object. But you can do it using `duration_cast` to convert time difference first to `hours` and then `minutes` and `seconds`.

After that using C++11 `to_string` function you can concatenate them to get the resulting string.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    steady_clock::time_point start = /* Some point in time */;
    steady_clock::time_point now = steady_clock::now();

    int hhh = duration_cast<hours>(now - start).count();
    int mm = duration_cast<minutes>(now - start).count() % 60;
    int ss = duration_cast<seconds>(now - start).count() % 60;

    std::ostringstream stream;
    stream << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3) << hhh << ':' <<
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << mm << ':' << 
        std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << ss;
    std::string result = stream.str();

}
```

Comment: This is the most logical from the examples on my link. I was just hoping there might be a way to use something like `put_time`. Nevermind. +1 :)

Comment: @learnvst, note I fixed a mistake here, I used 3 times `hours` as a template parameter.

Comment: @learnvst If you want to specifically format the numbers, you can easily do that with `std::ostringstream` and the normal output stream formatting manipulators.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I updated to use ostringstream with fixed-width output of numbers.

Comment: You can also use `operator%` with durations directly, see [example at cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/operator_arith4)

Comment: But `operator%` returns duration itself, so I have to use `count` member function anyway, don't I?

Comment: Don't use `.count()` until the very end. It's best to use the rich type system provided by `<chrono>` as long as possible rather than switch too early to generic types like `int`. See Howard Hinnant's answer.